# Angular won't update value (or does set it back?) by clicking on OpenLayers - Map

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers, getter, setter

My first project does include OpenMaps / Openlayers. The component I'm talking about looks like this:

```
import {AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Map, MapBrowserEvent, View} from 'ol';
import {OSM} from "ol/source";
import {fromLonLat, toLonLat} from "ol/proj";
import {defaults, MousePosition} from "ol/control";

import {createStringXY, toStringHDMS} from "ol/coordinate";
import {Tile} from "ol/layer";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  latitude: number = 52.520008;
  longitude: number = 13.404954;
  private map?: Map;
  view?: View;

  _lastClicked: string;

  constructor() {
    this._lastClicked = 'abc'; // his won't chang in frontend
  }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let osmTile = new Tile({
      source: new OSM()
    });

    this.view = new View({
      center: fromLonLat([this.longitude, this.latitude]),
      zoom: 8
    });

    let mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
      coordinateFormat: createStringXY(4),
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;',
      className: 'custom-mouse-position',
      target: document.getElementById('mouse-position') || undefined
    });
    let controls = defaults({
      attributionOptions: {
        collapsible: false
      }
    }).extend([mousePositionControl]);

    this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      controls: controls,
      layers: [
        osmTile
      ],
      view: this.view
    });
    this.map.on('click', this.onClick);
  }

  onClick(evt: MapBrowserEvent) {
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    this.lastClicked = toStringHDMS(toLonLat(coordinate));
    console.log(this.lastClicked + ' was clicked'); // this prints the correct values
  }


  get lastClicked(): string {
    return this._lastClicked;
  }

  set lastClicked(value: string) {
    this._lastClicked = value;
  }
  
  checkCoordinate() {
    console.log(this.lastClicked + ' is current position'); // this prints the wrong value
  }
}
```

while the html of that component looks like this

```
<h1>There is a map</h1>
  {{lastClicked}}
  <p>
    <button (click)="checkCoordinate()"> checkCoordinate</button>
  </p>
  <div id="mouse-position"></div>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</div>
```

The Result (with console on the right) looks like this:

[image: Component when started]

After first clicking on the map, the console shows the right output, while the value on top is still 'abc':
[image: Component when coordinate was clicked]
(Also of course the debugging shows that the coordinate is indeed safed in the property  `lastChecked`.)

Now I click on the button  (checkCoordinate), but somhow the **original value** (namely 'abc') is printed.

[image]
(Also of course the debugging shows that the old value is indeed set in the property  `lastChecked`.)

I really feel like I missed something not mentioned in the tutorials and material I got while learning Angular. Please help me to understand.

EDIT:

I debugged and found the following cause/problem:
[image]
That's not the root cause. Anyway "this" is not my original component (which I called MapComponent) but the ol/Map.

This is not the solution, but I'm a step closer.

Comment: I think the property is messing with the detection. You don't need that property. Just remove the `lastClicked` property and change `_lastClicked` to `lastClicked`

Comment: This setter is just for easier debugging. Anywhere I did what you suggested and it really doesn't help. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anybody needs that, but I found the solution.

Please note that parts of the code are totally unnecessary or irritating (means the code is not totally clean at this point) but it fits the mean.

The problem was (as mentioned in the EDIT of the original post) that the `this.map.on('click', this.onClick);` sets the function for the ol/Map. This causes that every `this` in the `onClick`-method becomes an `ol/Map`, so it does not resemble the angular component anymore. Simplier spoken this means that `this.lastClicked = ...` inside this method does not apply a value to anything like `MapComponent.lastClicked` but something like `MapComponent.map.lastClicked`.
So to show the value, I had to read it directly out of the `ol/Map`.

I also reorganised the modules a little bit because there was to much happening around.

But lets come to the implementation:

First, this is the new MapComponent with its html.

```js
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Map} from 'ol';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class MapComponent   {

  constructor() {
  }

  onMapReady($event: Map) {
    console.log("Map Ready")
  }

  meld(evt: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("Meld!")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>There is a map</h1>
  <app-ol-map class="map"
              [center]="[13.404954, 52.520008]"
              [zoom]="8.5"
              (click)="meld($event)"
  ></app-ol-map>
</div>
```

(There is also a bit of css in the background, but it's not really important at this point.)

You see that there is a `(click)` - method here, that doesn't do much, but it will cause the component to be aware of click-events thus causes the update on relating changes.

In Addition I stole another component from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-ol-simplemap?file=src/app/ol-map/ol-map.component.ts), named it OlMapComponent and modified it:

```js
import {AfterViewInit, Component, EventEmitter, Input, NgZone, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Map, MapBrowserEvent, View} from 'ol';
import {Coordinate, createStringXY, toStringHDMS} from 'ol/coordinate';
import {defaults, MousePosition} from 'ol/control';
import Projection from 'ol/proj/Projection';
import {fromLonLat, get as GetProjection, toLonLat} from 'ol/proj'
import {Extent} from 'ol/extent';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import {Tile} from "ol/layer";
import VectorLayer from "ol/layer/Vector";
import {Vector} from "ol/source";
import {KML} from "ol/format";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-ol-map',
  templateUrl: './ol-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ol-map.component.scss']
})
export class OlMapComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() center?: Coordinate;
  @Input() zoom?: number;
  view: View | undefined;
  projection: Projection | undefined;
  extent: Extent = [-20026376.39, -20048966.10, 20026376.39, 20048966.10];
  map: Map | undefined;
  plzLayer?: VectorLayer;
  @Output() mapReady = new EventEmitter<Map>();


  get lastClicked(): string {
    // @ts-ignore
    return this.map?.lastClicked || 'undefined';
  }

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (!this.map) {
      this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => this.initMap())
    }
    setTimeout(() => this.mapReady.emit(this.map));
  }

  private initMap(): void {
    this.projection = GetProjection('EPSG:3857');
    this.projection.setExtent(this.extent);
    let osmTile = new Tile({
      source: new OSM()
    });
    this.plzLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: new Vector({
        url: 'assets/kml/Postleitzahlengebiete.kml',
        format: new KML(),
      })
    });

    this.view = new View({
       center: fromLonLat(this.center || [13.404954, 52.520008]),
       zoom: this.zoom || 8,
       projection: this.projection
    });

    let mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
      coordinateFormat: createStringXY(4),
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;',
      className: 'custom-mouse-position',
      target: document.getElementById('mouse-position') || undefined
    });
    let controls = defaults({
      attributionOptions: {
        collapsible: false
      }
    }).extend([mousePositionControl]);

    this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      controls: controls,
      layers: [
        osmTile,
        this.plzLayer
      ],
      view: this.view
    });
    this.map.on('click', this.onClick);
  }

  onClick(evt: MapBrowserEvent) {
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    // @ts-ignore
    // calling from the ol/Map (by defining it as its "on('click',...) - Method, 'this' is the ol/Map itself, not the
    // component anymore!!! (IntelliJ may be lying to you, but you will see it in the debug)
    this.lastClicked = toStringHDMS(toLonLat(coordinate));
    const lcc = document.getElementById('lastClicked') || undefined;
    if (lcc) lcc.innerHTML = 'Located click is: <code>' + this.lastClicked +
      '</code>';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="lastClicked"></div>
<div>Current value is: <code>{{lastClicked}}</code></div>
<div class="map-container" id="map"></div>
```

I now 'correctly' treat `this` in the `onClick` method as an instance `ol/Map`. Unfortunately this means that I save the value `lastClicked` not in the component but in the `ol/Map` itself. To display it in the frontend, I wrote a getter which just delegates the value.

Of course my IDE does not approve this. Therefore I have to use `@ts-ignore.

But what can I say? It works.
Initially I get this: [image]

Nothing unexpected, but not different from my first approach.

The 'magic' happens when I click:
[image]

As you can see, the value is played correctly twice:

1. by delgating via `get lastClicked(): string { // @ts-ignore return this.map?.lastClicked || 'undefined'; }`
2. by manipulating the dom via  `const lcc = document.getElementById('lastClicked') || undefined; if (lcc) lcc.innerHTML = 'Located click is: <code>' + this.lastClicked + '</code>';`

Also the on `click` Method of `MapComponent` is called. This might be helpful for the future, but primarily it causes the underlying `OlMapComponent` to update the shown value.